# Striker's bails off during delivery

Tags: rules, cricket

What happens if the bails fall off at the striker's end during the delivery?

I understand that the umpire should call and signal dead ball so the batsman cannot be out nor should he attempt runs and if he does they will not count. The ball does not count as one of the over. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, as stated in [20.4.2.4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/dead-ball) the ball becomes automatically dead:

> Either umpire shall call and signal Dead ball when [...] one or both bails fall from the striker’s wicket before the striker has had the opportunity of playing the ball.

From that point on the ball is dead and nothing further can happen.  As also stated in the laws the ball doesn't count as one for the over.

The general principle is if the batsmen has not had the opportunity to play the ball it shall not count as one for the over.

Comment: I've copied the text of the law in here to make the answer standalone - the MCC have an unfortunate habit of breaking links to their website every time when they revamp it every few years or so.